# hapijs how to check the session in each request

Tags: session-cookies, hapi.js

i would like to know what is the best way to check h.state on every call to hapijs service.

I create the session like this:

```
server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/createSession',
    config: {
        cors: {
            origin: ['mysite']


        }
    },
    handler: function (request, h) {
        let cookie = request.state.session

        if (!cookie) {
            cookie = {
                username: 'emiliano',
                firstVisit: false                   
            }
        }
        cookie.lastVisit = Date.now()
        return h.response('test').state('session', cookie)
    }

});
```

how can I check if the cookie is present in each request?
 is it possible to do this in server.ext?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lifecycle methods of the Hapi and create a simple plugin to check cookies in every request. You can use `onPreHandler` because hapi will execute `onPreHandler` just before route handlers and after cookies (state) handled internally. If you want to interfere before everything else (before cookie parsing) you can use `onRequest`.

Here is simple plugin that you can use. You can also read more about life cycle methods [here](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#request-lifecycle)

```
exports.plugin = {
    async register(server, options) {
        server.ext('onPreHandler', async (request, h) => {
            // do your cookie stuff here

            return h.continue;
        });      
    },
    name: 'check-cookie'    
};
```